# Developer folder on the HDD on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4

Tags: xcode, macos

I expected to see a "Developer folder" on the HDD and I'm using Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 but there is none.

[image: www.kerrydeaf.com/apple.png]

I've downloaded 'Command Line Tools for Xcode' from 'Downloads Apple Developers' with [this link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action)

I'll be using HTML, CSS and Javascript to develop an app through Xcode. I've Xcode installed and registered with Apple. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that they scrapped the /Developer folder, and are now keeping everything inside the /Applications/Xcode.app/...

Comment: Really, that is interesting so I'm beating myself up for nothing? Where did you hear this?

Comment: I have seen this on my Mac :-) My Build tool now accesses the SDks via "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/..."; I didn't really crosscheck with old installs, but I'd guess they just moved the whole folder into Xcode.app as it was.

Comment: Was there announcement by Apple or on internet that says so? I only see "/Applications/Xcode.app/".

Comment: I don't know. I just noticed that the box didn't get a /Developer folder after installing Xcode, so I searched for it to find out where it went. After all, it's not like I can't live without a /Developer folder, as long as the contents are still available :-)

Comment: Ok I'll leave it then. Thank you.